# Continuous Functions in Metric Spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The following question is from Fred H. Croom's book "Principles of Topology"

> > Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a function on the indicated metric space. Prove that the following statements are equivalent:
> >
> > 1. $f$ is continuous.
> > 2. For each subset $A$ of $X$, $f(\bar{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$
> > 3. For each subset $B$ of $Y$, $f^{-1}($int$B) \subset $ int$f^{-1}(B)$

I would figure, the way to prove these statements are equivalent is by going in a circle. By this I mean, (1) implies (2), (2) implies (3), and (3) implies (1). Sadly this is where I am stuck because I am not sure how to go from one statement to the other.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

---

I want to thank you for taking the time to read this question. I greatly appreciate any assistance you provide.

Answer (score 1):

To show $(1) \implies (2)$, let $A$ be a subset of $X$. Given $y\in f(\bar{A})$, there is an $x\in \bar{A}$ such that $f(x) = y$. Since $x\in \bar{A}$, there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = x$. Since $f$ is continuous, $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(a_n) = f(x)$, i.e., $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(a_n) = y$. Since $(f(a_n))$ is a sequence in $f(A)$, $y$ is a limit point of $f(A)$. Thus $y\in \overline{f(A)}$.

To show $(2) \implies (3)$, use the fact that $X\setminus \operatorname{int} A = \overline{X\setminus A}$ for all subsets $A$ of $X$.

Finally, to show that $(3)\implies (1)$, let $d$ be the metric on $X$. Given  $\epsilon > 0$ and $c\in X$, set $B = \{y\in Y : d(y,f(c)) < \epsilon\}$. Then $B$ is an open subset of $Y$. So by hypothesis, $f^{-1}(B) \subset \operatorname{int}f^{-1}(B)$. This implies $f^{-1}(B)$ is an open subset of $X$. Since $c\in f^{-1}(B)$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x\in X$, $d(x,c) < \delta$ implies $x\in f^{-1}(B)$, i.e., $d(x,c) < \delta$ implies $d(f(x),f(c)) < \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing them in reverse order as well.

For 1) implies 3), continuity says preimages of open sets are open. Then since $int(B)$ is an open set contained in $B$, $f^{-1}(int(B))$ is an open set contained in $f^{-1}(B)$.

For 3) implies 2), use complements. $\overline{f(A)}=Y\setminus int(Y\setminus f(A))$, and $f(\overline{A})=f(X\setminus int(X\setminus A)$.

For 2) implies 1), suppose $x_n \rightarrow x$ and use that for each subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ the closure of $\{x_{n_k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is precisely $\{x_{n_k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{x\}$. Combine this with 2) and argue that it must be that $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$.